# The component type of a list turns to be String which actually is declared to be Duration

Tags: java, list

I have a customized object including fields:

```
private List<Duration> durations;
private Duration single;
```

When debugging, I evaluate the following expression and the result is `java.lang.String` which is different from the declared type. Why?

```
durations.get(0).getClass()
```

As a comparison, the class of `single` is `Duration`, same as declared type.

If any help, I got the data deserialized from MySQL.

Comment: can you paste the java code here instead of providing images.

Comment: code pasted and problem updated

Answer (score 0):

getClass gives you the runtime class of the Object.

Here is a short example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class T {
  String sam = "jack";
  public String getSam() {return sam;}
  public void setSam(String sam) {this.sam = sam;}
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    T t = new T();
    list.add(t);
    Class<? extends T> c = list.get(0).getClass();
    System.out.println(list.get(0).getSam().getClass());
  }
}
```

Which means you can't operate normal operations on the variable as you do when you initialize a class variable with the keyword new.

So, `t.getSam() is possible whereas c.getSam()` is invalid.

If you need further clarification, then provide the full class Duration and what objective that you are looking for.

Comment: class Duration is java.time.Duration

Comment: As I mentioned, I got the property deserialized from a json string which is like `setDurations(List.of("a", "b"))`. As a result, the actual type of arguments of the `List` is String instead of Duration. All because Java won't check actual type of arguments of `ParameterizedType`, right?

Comment: provide all the relevant data, like Duration class, without that it's not possible to pin point your issue.

Comment: problem solved. Thanks anyway.